# Redirect .com domain to .dk/en

Tags: i18n-l10n, redirection

I have a site; www.example.net. If you type www.example.com it redirects to www.example.net which is okay.

On my site i have to different language prefixes /da and /en that you can switch between.

My question: is it possible to redirect all who try to visit the site via www.example.com to www.example.net/en?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `.htaccess`,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.net/en [R,L]
```

Where `www.example.com` is your old domain and `www.example.net`is the new one.

Comment: Thanks!
I found out that I had been doing it right. The problem had to do with some DNS settings.